# How can I make two plugins receive and send messages to each other?

Tags: c#, plugins

I'm trying to make plugins for apps called RainMeter and MusicBee using C# to control Media and extract data from MusicBee. So I want to make them communicate with each other like sending requests and handling events. The plugins will be on the same computer.

Something like:

```
Plugin1_SendMessage(Event info);//This sends a message from plugin1 to plugin2
Plugin2_OnReceiveMessage(Event info)
{
    //This function runs when it receives a message
    //Handle the event
}

Plugin2_SendMessage(Event info);//This sends a message from plugin2 to plugin1
Plugin1_OnReceiveMessage(Event info)
{
    //This function runs when it receives a message
    //Handle the event
}
```

I'm sorry if I can't describe it much but I just want a way for them to communicate locally without hosting a WebSocket if possible.

Edit: It became a huge pain in the neck to try pipes so now I'm just using WebSocket.

Edit: Currently getting back to using named pipes.

Comment: There are three methods 1) Use Standard Input/Output to connect apps 2) Use a Name Pipe 3) Connect through a socket which can be http, tcp, or udp.  One app can be a websocket and the other a webclient to connect the two apps.

Comment: Option 2 seems to be a good way. I'll get back to you after I try it.

Comment: What's the difference between named pipes and anonymous pipes? Also, are named pipes better than anonymous pipes for this scenario?

Comment: Pipes are becoming a lot more complicated than I imagined so I'm sticking to WebSocket for now.

Comment: Both are streams.  Inside an application a stream is a variable that gets accessed by the variable name.  When connecting to a stream from another application you need a name to make the connection.

Comment: A response stream is no different that a pipe.  What complications are you having?

Comment: From what I saw (correct me if I'm wrong) is that named pipes are better than anonymous pipes because I can run them on separate directories. It's that I am having a bit of a hard time understanding Microsoft's official documentation for named pipes. I don't understand what their example is supposed to do. Could you look at it and tell me what it should do?

Comment: I'm using folowing webpage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication  When two application communicate one is always the Server and the other the Client (even if it is not a network connection).  So the server always starts first and waits for client to connect. The server has to open the Pipe (stream) and then waits for client to connect.  The Server is the slave and client the master.  So communications is usually client sends a command and server responds to the command and sends a reply.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, that is the right webpage. I was having trouble with how communication worked so that clarifies it a bit, but from what I see the program doesn't listen for events but instead keeps communicating non-stop (again correct me if I'm wrong), is there a way for the program or a function run only when it receives a message from the client?

Comment: Microsoft examples are simple to show one concept.  You can always add additional features like asynchronous interfaces instead of synchronous.

Comment: Ok, I can now see a way to do it. Thanks, I'll get back if I finish it or have another problem.

Comment: I tested it with bare minimum client and server programs and I now made it continuously interact with each other. I don't know about being perfect but it does get the job done. I can now implement it in my plugins. Thank you so much.